# How do I apply colors to a multi color svg in flutter?

Tags: flutter, svg, dart, flutter-web

I am looking for changing colors of an illustration svg in flutter. I tried flutter_svg package but it support applying only one color to the svg and if I do that svg will be displayed as a single color svg, individual colors are lost. Is there any way to change colors at runtime in flutter for a multi color svg?

Comment: You got any solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60946115/interacting-with-svg-in-flutter
This is somewhat a solution but I haven't figured it out how to make the color stick because on this example the color goes back to normal when clicked outside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? I call it SVG colorization.

[image: SVG Colorization App Demo]

I'll try to squeeze the concept into a short summary. In an SVG file, you need to play around with the `fill` property as it defines the hex color code.

In terms of programming, you would:

1. Extract the SVG file data as a `String` variable `svgCode`.

[image: Illustration of SVG File Data Extraction into String svgCode]

2. Assign the previous hex color code in `previousColor` & the currently selected hex color code in `newColor`.

[image: Illustration of hex color code assignment to variables previousColor & newColor]

3. Apply the `String.replaceAll` method on `svgCode` to replace the colors.

[image: Illustration of hex color code replacement]

4. Update the value of the `previousColor`.

[image: Illustration of previousColor value updation]

A more brief elaboration would be

```dart
/// Initially without any color selection.
SVGPicture.string('''<svg code with fill #f7ebcb>''');
```

```dart
/// After the user selects the red color.
SVGPicture.string('''<svg code with fill #FF0000>''');
```

[This tutorial](https://zujaj.hashnode.dev/how-to-color-switch-an-svg-in-flutter) can help to solve your issue. Not only does [this app](https://svg-colorization.web.app/) changes the color on runtime, but it also allows the user to download the manipulated SVG code.